# Problem in Concept building

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I know, that if a polynomial function fails to have any real root, then, by the fundamental theorem of algebra, it must possess at least a pair of complex roots having non-zero imaginary part. The real roots are points of intersection of the curve, with the horizontal axis, on the real plane. My problem is in visualising location of complex roots. Can I make use of Argand Plane in visualising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect.

The Argand plane, or complex plane, specifically allows a visualization of complex numbers.

These two links provide a good introduction in various representations of complex numbers:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane
2. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexPlane.html

If you had a list of the roots of your polynomial, you could plot them on the Argand plane.  The real roots would be on the real axis, the imaginary roots would be on the imaginary axis and the complex roots would be points in the plane according to the values of their real and imaginary parts.

Don't confuse this description of the plot of the roots with a graph of the polynomial, though.  If you graph the polynomial in the cartesian (real) plane with x and y axis, then, as you stated, you would see the real roots where the graph intersects the x-axis.  You do not see the complex roots on the graph of the polynomial.

Comment: If I consider f(x)=(x^2)+2x+2, and equate it to zero, then we get complex roots {-1+i,-1-i}. So, I would have the ordered pairs (-1,i),  (-1,-i) on Argand plane. Both of them have real part -1, and imaginary part {i,-i}. We cannot call -1 a real root, nor the values {i,-i} imaginary roots, for they individually do not satisfy f(x)=0.

Comment: You are correct, this polynomial,f, has two complex roots:  (-1,i) and (-1,-i). There would be two points on the complex plane.  The polynomial g(x)=((x^2)+2x+2)(x-2) would have an additional root at the point (2,0).